# cómo cambiar el valor en secuencia al generar un ID?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, apex

Hola estoy aprendiendo SQL, y estoy creando una secuencia que me ayude a generar id automaticamente al cerrar un registro en un formulario.
Mi secuencia la hice así:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE   "CAMPANA_SEQ" 
 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999
 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 41 
CACHE 20 ORDER  NOCYCLE 
 NOKEEP  NOSCALE  GLOBAL
```

y tengo un trigger asi:

```
create or replace trigger "BI_CAMPANA"
BEFORE
insert on "CAMPANA"
for each row
begin
IF :NEW.ID_CAMPANA IS NULL THEN 
    SELECT CAMPANA_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID_CAMPANA FROM SYS.DUAL;
END IF;
end;
```

El problema es que al iniciar los registros se generaron bien los id pero cuando elimino algun registro y quiero generar uno nuevo me toma como ultimo valor a partir de 20 y el id que se generar es 21, supongo que esto lo esta tomando del valor que puse en cache, quisiera saber como hacer para solucionar esto y que siga los correlativos.

Si alguien me puede explicar o ayudar a solucionar esto por favor. Apenas estoy aprendiendo y hay muchas cosas que desconozco.

Comment: No. Los agujeros no se llenan.. porque no deberias llenarlos.. porque no es para eso crear una secuencia... Si vos queres llenar agujeros, tenes que programar algo que los busque y los llene... La pregunta es, porque querrias llenar agujeros?

Comment: @gbianchi a que te refieres con agujeros?, disculpa mi ignorancia estoy aprendiendo.

Comment: nada que pedir disculpas... Si eliminas, quedara un agujero.. (o sea tenes ponele el 50,51,53 porque borraste el 52)... porque querrias regenerarlo??? muchas veces, la entrada en orden tambien ayuda si no tenes una fecha... pero en general no llenas agujeros, no tenes porque....

Comment: Exacto despues que tenia mi secuencia bien la borre para reiniciarla con los datos correctos y ahi fue donde todo se daño y ahora comienza a contar desde el 20 en adelante, como puedo hacer para reinicarlo y que comience en uno?

Comment: porque??? si es una especie de TOC, olvidalo, las DB hacen lo que quieren con eso.. si queres reiniciarle tenes que hacer una nueva.. pero, repito, NO DEBERIA IMPORTARTE... si te importa, es otra cosa entonces...

Comment: Si te entiendo, lo que pasa es que yo ingrese datos porque estaba haciendo pruebas y por eso los borre y ahora que voy a insertar los datos correctos no puedo porque el id esta iniciando en 21, pareciera que faltan 20 registros!

Comment: no falta nada... NO IMPORTA.. el id es solo como referencia.. no significa nada!!! igual si queres reiniciarlo, no se si tenes que hacer uno nuevo o podes hacer un alter.. no lo recuerdo.. pero.. NO IMPORTA!!!!!

Comment: Gracias, pense que me iba a afectar al ingresar los datos en las tablas.

Comment: Porque piensas que te va a afectar el ingreso en las tablas? esa es la respuesta que tengo que responderte ;)